# How is Symfony skipping some lines in test

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.8

I'm seeing some really bizarre behaviour from Symfony 2.8. I've added some `echo`s and `var_dump`s to some standard Symfony classes to try and work out what's going on.

This `Application` class extends the next one. I've added four `echo`s and a `var_dump` which are half-unindented:

`vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Console/Application.php`

```
<?php

namespace Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console;

use Symfony\Component\Console\Application as BaseApplication;

class Application extends BaseApplication
{
    private $kernel;

    public function __construct(KernelInterface $kernel)
    {
      echo "Construct Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application\n";
      echo get_class($this) . PHP_EOL;
      echo get_parent_class($this) . PHP_EOL;
        $this->kernel = $kernel;
      var_dump('Symfony', Kernel::VERSION.' - '.$kernel->getName().'/'.$kernel->getEnvironment().($kernel->isDebug() ? '/debug' : ''));

        parent::__construct('Symfony', Kernel::VERSION.' - '.$kernel->getName().'/'.$kernel->getEnvironment().($kernel->isDebug() ? '/debug' : ''));

        $this->getDefinition()->addOption(new InputOption('--shell', '-s', InputOption::VALUE_NONE, 'Launch the shell.'));
        $this->getDefinition()->addOption(new InputOption('--process-isolation', null, InputOption::VALUE_NONE, 'Launch commands from shell as a separate process.'));
        $this->getDefinition()->addOption(new InputOption('--env', '-e', InputOption::VALUE_REQUIRED, 'The Environment name.', $kernel->getEnvironment()));
        $this->getDefinition()->addOption(new InputOption('--no-debug', null, InputOption::VALUE_NONE, 'Switches off debug mode.'));
      echo "Finished constructing Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application\n";
    }
```

This is the base `Application` class. I've only added an `echo` to this class, which is also half-unindented:

`vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php`

```
<?php

namespace Symfony\Component\Console;

class Application
{
    private $name;
    private $version;
    private $definition;
    private $helperSet;
    private $defaultCommand;

    public function __construct($name = 'UNKNOWN', $version = 'UNKNOWN')
    {
      echo "--> Construct Symfony\Component\Console\Application\n";
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->version = $version;
        $this->defaultCommand = 'list';
        $this->helperSet = $this->getDefaultHelperSet();
        $this->definition = $this->getDefaultInputDefinition();

        foreach ($this->getDefaultCommands() as $command) {
            $this->add($command);
        }
    }
```

When I run `php app/console hmrx:app:filecheck` I get this:

```
Construct Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application
Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application
Symfony\Component\Console\Application
C:\server\Apache24\htdocs\dev.hmr-app\hmrex\HMRX_App\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application.php:44:
string(7) "Symfony"
C:\server\Apache24\htdocs\dev.hmr-app\hmrex\HMRX_App\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application.php:44:
string(21) "2.8.2 - app/dev/debug"
--> Construct Symfony\Component\Console\Application
Finished constructing Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application
```

And when I run the same code via a test I get this:

```
Construct Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application
Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application
Symfony\Component\Console\Application
C:\server\Apache24\htdocs\dev.hmr-app\hmrex\HMRX_App\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application.php:44:
string(7) "Symfony"
C:\server\Apache24\htdocs\dev.hmr-app\hmrex\HMRX_App\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application.php:44:
string(21) "2.8.2 - app/dev/debug"
Finished constructing Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application
```

Please note the output is identical except for the second last line `--> Construct Symfony\Component\Console\Application`, which is missing when run as part of the test. It appears that `parent::__construct('Symfony', Kernel::VERSION.' - '.$kernel->getName().'/'.$kernel->getEnvironment().($kernel->isDebug() ? '/debug' : ''));` is not being run. How can PHP/Symfony possibly skip running a line that doesn't have a condition on it?

Comment: I'd hazard a random guess that `Application` has been mocked - and the mock's constructor was called instead of your concrete implementation. (but I'd want to drill into this more if I were to add this as an answer)

Comment: @HPierce It hasn't been mocked. I'm constructing the class directly in the test, and verifying that the correct class has been constructed. I even asked the derived class what its parent is (in the output above), and the answer is the same in both cases.

Comment: I've worked it out, but not how to fix it yet! My test framework (Codeception) includes some Symfony classes. Since, they're already loaded, Symfony doesn't load them again, leading to different behaviour!